# laravel post data and redirect to the same post url without form submit

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I need to `post` data to a payment service(payment.com), and `redirect` to payment.com(to fill credit card number etc.)

The traditional way to do it is like this:

```html
<form id="form" action="payment.com" method="POST">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('form').submit();
</script>
```

> But I want to do it through a `controller`, not submit by a form, so no
>   data could be changed.

---

This is my controller method, and I've tried two ways:`redirect()` and `Guzzle`

1. I tried to `redirect()` to the url with post data, but I got **"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."**

```php
public function postToPaymentServer(Request $request)
{
    $amount=$request['amount'];
    $payment=[
        'amount'=>$amount,
        'auth-id'=>config('auth-id')
    ];
    return redirect(url('api/payment/server'))->with(compact('payment'));
}
```

ps. Here I made a local route to simulate the payment.com in routes/api.php

```php
Route::post('payment/server','PaymentController@server');
```

---

2. I tried to use `Guzzle`, but it **wouldn't redirect to the post url**.

```php
public function postToPaymentServer(Request $request)
{
    $amount=$request['amount'];
    $payment=[
        'amount'=>$amount,
        'auth-id'=>config('auth-id')
    ];
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->post('payment.com',[
        'body'=>[
            'payment'=>$payment,
            'allow_redirects' => true
        ],
    ]);
    return $response;
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to manually do the redirect (`return redirect()`) after making the post request with guzzle. What does the payment.com documentation tell you to do exactly? Is the url you need to redirect to part of the data returned from the api request?

Comment: @Jeemusu The payment.com documentation tell me to post payment data through form submit

Comment: @Autodesk change `$client->post(url('payment.com')` to `$client->post('http://payment.com')`

Comment: @Jeemusu The redirect url and the post url are the same:payment.com

Comment: Thank you @AdityaThakur, in fact it is my typing error...lol

Comment: @Autodesk what is the expected response from your gateway?

Comment: @AdityaThakur I hope it behave like a <form> submission, post and redirect to payment.com, so no response is expected

Comment: @Autodesk The Guzzle requests take place in the server, once the form is posted to the controller guzzle will make a request and execute it in server but it will not redirect the user to payment page.

Comment: @AdityaThakur thank you, I see, no wonder it didn't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve last location from redirect history and redirect to this location.

Look at the **track_redirects** option:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions;

$httpClient = new Client();

$response = $httpClient->post(
    'http://payment.com',
    [
        RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS => [
            'max' => 5,
            'track_redirects' => true,
        ],
        RequestOptions::FORM_PARAMS => [
            'payment' => $payment,
        ],
    ]
);

$lastLocation = end($response->getHeaders()['X-Guzzle-Redirect-History']);

return redirect($lastLocation);
```